# Create Application from code and load resource dictionnary from xaml

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary

This might be an extremely dumb question, but I simply can't understand the problem at the moment.

I have an App.xaml file that defines application level resources :

```
<Application x:Class="WpfMPManager.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"             
         StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="MyDictionnary.xaml"/>                   
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

For various reasons, I start this application through a .cs file like that (there actually is a lot more going on in this file).

```
   [STAThread]
    static void Main(params string[] args)
    {
        App myApp = new App();
        MainWindow myWindow = new MainWindow();
        myApp.Run(myWindow);
     }
```

However, when I start the application in this way, my application resource dictionnaries are empty (and they are indeed filled if I start the application through my App.xml).

Should I call a specific method on the Application object to force it to load the resource dictionaries defined in the .xaml file ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question in case anyone stumbles on that

It seems it's enough to call `myApp.InitializeComponent()` which is not called by the default constructor. Could have figured it out faster.